# How to copy the contents of one row in a table to another table and add the identical ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var Sell_Button = document.getElementById('sellbtn'),
  secondTable = document.getElementById("secondTableBody");

Sell_Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

      var Row = secondTable.insertRow();

      for (var c = 0; c < 2; c += 1) {
        Row.insertCell(c);
      }

      Row.cells[0].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
      Row.cells[2].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
  
      //checks to see if the secondTable has a row containing the same name
      for (var f = 0; f < secondTable.rows.length; f += 1) {
        //adds only the sold amount if the second table has a row with the same name
//error            
if (secondTable.rows[f].cells[0].innerText === this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerText) {
          secondTable.rows[f].cells[1].innerHTML = +this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
          //deletes an extra row that is added at the bottom
          if (secondTable.rows.length > 1) {
            secondTable.deleteRow(secondTable.rows.length - 1);
          }
          //if nothing matched then a new row is added
        } else {
          secondTable.insertRow();
          Row.cells[0].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
          Row.cells[1].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="firstTableDiv">
    <table border="1" id="firstTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th colspan="1">Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="firstTableBody">
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td>
            <button id="sellbtn">Sell</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>100</td>
          <td>
            <button id="sellbtn">Sell</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Oranges</td>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>
            <button id="sellbtn">Sell</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </br>

  <div id="secondTableDiv">
    Sold

    <table border="1" id="secondTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="secondTableBody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Ok, this example isn't exactly what i'm working on but it's very similar. The only difference is that in mine the rows and buttons are dynamically added by the user and he inserts the details. What I want is that when i press on the button of each row (sell) the details (Item and Sold only) are copied into a row in the second table and checks if the same item exists in this second table if so then it adds the amount of sold of both items in one row. For instance I press on the first row button the Apples it copies the listed above details to the second table in a row and then when i click on the button of the second row (Apples also) it only adds the sold amount up and doesn't add a second apples row because an apples row already exists in the second table but when i click on the oranges button it makes a new row because the oranges row doesn't exist. So how do I do this in JavaScript? i hope i was thorough and made any sense. I have no idea why the code isn't working here but i hope you get the point. This code works perfectly just as i want it to until for some reason i get this error:  Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined when i press the buttons approx. 6-7 times targeting the if statement where i commented error.

Comment: can jquery be used or u need the solution in plain javascript??

Comment: @BalajiViswanath yes, no problem with jquery

Comment: First of all your code isn't jQuery at the moment so using multiple buttons with the same id and attaching event handlers to it isn't going to work.

Comment: @Mouser My real code is actually written in both plain JS and jQuery so that's one thing and the buttons are dynamically added using the createElement and have an onclick attached to them in which i target the cells of the row of the clicked button using this.parentNode and $(this).closest() and such and it's all working good except for this. Like i said works perfectly fine until 6-7 clicks then gets me an error

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#firstTable tr button", function(b) {
    b = $(this).closest("tr");
    var d = $.trim(b.find("td:first").text());
    b = parseFloat($.trim(b.find("td:nth-child(3)").text()));
    var a = $("#secondTable"),
        c = a.find("tr").filter(function(a) {
            return $.trim($(this).find("td:first").text()) == d
        });
    c.length ? (a = c.find("td:nth-child(2)"), c = parseFloat($.trim(a.text())), a.text(b + c)) : (a = $("<tr />").appendTo(a), $("<td />", {
        text: d
    }).appendTo(a), $("<td />", {
        text: b
    }).appendTo(a))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstTableDiv">
 <table border="1" id="firstTable">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sold</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="firstTableBody">
   <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td><button>Sell</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td><button>Sell</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td><button>Sell</button></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="secondTableDiv">
 Sold
 <table border="1" id="secondTable">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Sold</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="secondTableBody"></tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, we both did it. For the completeness update the html and remove the repeating id's from the button :-)

Comment: @Mouser "To jQuery, or not To jQuery. Which is the solution?" :-P

Comment: I like vanilla ice baby ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This sets a click handler to all buttons. If the row doesn't exist in the second table it's created. It sets a `data-type` referring to the item. When somebody clicks the `sell` button again and there is a row containing the data-type the row is updated instead of created. All in plain JavaScript.

```js
var Sell_Button = document.querySelectorAll('.sellbtn'),
  secondTable = document.getElementById("secondTableBody");

Array.prototype.slice.call(Sell_Button).forEach(function(element){

 element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  //since the button is an element without children use e.
  var clickedElement = e.target;
  var parentRow = clickedElement.parentNode.parentNode;
  
  //check if second table has a row with data-type
  var rowWithData = secondTable.querySelector("[data-type='"+parentRow.cells[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"']");
  if (rowWithData)
  {
   rowWithData.cells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(rowWithData.cells[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + parseInt(parentRow.cells[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
  else
  {
   var Row = secondTable.insertRow();
            Row.setAttribute("data-type", parentRow.cells[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

   for (var c = 0; c < 2; c += 1) {
    Row.insertCell(c);
   }
   Row.cells[0].innerHTML = parentRow.cells[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   Row.cells[1].innerHTML = parentRow.cells[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }

 });
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="firstTableDiv">
    <table border="1" id="firstTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th colspan="1">Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="firstTableBody">
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td>
            <button class="sellbtn">Sell</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>100</td>
          <td>
            <button class="sellbtn">Sell</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Oranges</td>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>
            <button class="sellbtn">Sell</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </br>

  <div id="secondTableDiv">
    Sold

    <table border="1" id="secondTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="secondTableBody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: TY, nice answer as well. Guess the OP has plenty of choice in solution. lol

Comment: @SpYk3HH He just needs to do *eeny meeny miny moe* and start with my solution

Comment: bleh, after almost 2 whole decades of vanilla, i like adding flavor ;-)

Comment: @SpYk3HH Vanilla is also a flavor :'-(